# Capturar valor de datepicker y colorpicker en un String en javaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Pues en mi programa tengo un datePicker y un colorpicker, lo que quiero hacer es que al presionar un boton, se me muestre el valor del color seleccionaro y la fecha seleccionada.

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado? Podrías mostrarnos tu código para saber como ayudarte? Pásate por el [tour] y por [ask] para mas información.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes dejarnos tu código . de todas maneras dejo un ejemplo de interactuar con **colorpicker** y **datePicker** en un evento para botón.

```
    package ejemplo;
   import java.time.LocalDate;
   import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
  import javafx.event.EventHandler;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.control.Button;
  import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
  import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
  import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;


 public class Ejemplo extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    DatePicker datepicker = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
    datepicker.setTranslateY(-70);
    ColorPicker colorpicker = new ColorPicker();
    colorpicker.setTranslateY(-40);




    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("cambiar color y texto");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            btn.setTextFill(colorpicker.getValue());
            btn.setText(datepicker.getValue().toString());

        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(btn,datepicker,colorpicker);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("color y fecha ");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

la salida ( cambia el texto y el color del botón de acuerdo a lo seleccionado en **colorpicker** y **datepicker** ).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]